# How to use gspread_dataframe.set_with_dataframe and keep googlesheet original formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gspread

I am using `gspread_dataframe.set_with_dataframe` to add a dataframe to my google spreadsheet as follow:

```
d = {'col1': [0.4, 0.8], 'col2': [0.1, 0.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sheet = select_worksheet('1QuKquj6RECzmreJ-DwOyA-xfY4V2JpKd5YI44U4qswU',0)
set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)
```

The script above will fill column A and B of my spreadsheet. I have formerly formatted both columns directly on google sheet to be a percentage. However my percentage formatting is removed each time I run this script.

Can you please advise on how to keep the percentage formatting or if you have a workaround?

Comment: Can you provide your current script by removing your personal information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframe will override the formatting you have put on google spreadsheet.

In my case I needed to display percentage. To achieve this I directly format my column as percentage as follow:

`df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(float).map("{:.2%}".format)`

This is recognised by the spreadsheet as a percentage number.